# Improve Minecraft performance with Shaders

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, performance, minecraft-optifine

I have all details included at the bottom of this question.

I have Minecraft with Shaders Mod, and from what I can tell, my computer is perfectly capable of running it. However, I think my system is holding back.

The CPU usage is around 12%, and the GPU sticks around 76%.

I have tried the game with different graphics settings, and all the statistics stay in the same ballpark.

When I look at the sun in Minecraft dawn morning, the FPS meter drops to around 30. Everywhere else fluctuates (seemingly randomly) between 26 - 80 frames.

I want Minecraft to utilize my full system resources. I have set the `javaw.exe` to higher priorities, and stopped unnecessary processes to the extremes of `explorer.exe`.

Is there anything I can do to make minecraft actually *use* my computer?

I will add more information as requested, but as of now I can't think of anything else. Oh, and nothing wrong with my temps.

**Edit 1:** Forgot to add, Shaders mod is bundled with OptiFine.

All of the things like installed resourcepack, shader pack, matmos pack, etc... are in the options files.

```
System Specs:
ASUS Sabertooth X58
Nvidia Geforce GTX 760, 2GB GDDR5
Intel Core i7 X-980 Extreme Edition
12GB Corsair (Dominator?)
And some random 1TB Toshiba HDD I had laying around.
```

Minecraft settings: (pastebin)

[options.txt](http://pastebin.com/5yk9HGFD)

[optionsof.txt](http://pastebin.com/Z8Brfw36)

[optionsshaders.txt](http://pastebin.com/LzYN599P)

```
Currently Installed Mods:

AutoSwitch-v5.2.2-mc1.8.jar
CodeChickenCore-1.8-1.0.5.34-universal.jar
InventoryTweaks-1.59-176.jar
liteloader-1.8.jar
MC 1.8 - Smart Moving 16.2.zip
mobends-0.21.1_for_MC-1.8.jar
mod_MAtmos_29ub5_mc1.8.litemod
mod_voxelMap_1.5.18_for_1.8a.litemod
MouseTweaks-2.5.0-mc1.8.jar
NotEnoughItems-1.8-1.0.5.82-universal.jar
OptiFine_1.8.0_HD_U_F8.jar
PresenceFootsteps_u7b_1.8.litemod
ThebombzenAPI-v2.5.1-mc1.8.jar
[1.8]DamageIndicatorsMod-3.3.2.jar
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's about support of modded Minecraft. We only ask about support of vanilla Minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think my system is holding back.

This is incorrect, shaders are mostly dependant on your CPU. You state that your cpu is at 12%. I looked up your CPU the specs show there are 12 logical processors available with this CPU. 100/12 = 8.3, so the most any single core application could use is ~8% of your total CPU (The other 4% can easily be attributed to other random background processes). Go to the details tab of the task manager, and see how much Minecraft itself is using.

To resolve the problem you can either lower the graphics quality to reduce the load on the core or you could try installing a mod for minecraft that will allow it to utilize multiple cores.

OptiFine, one of the mods you have installed already, is capable of this:.

> The option "Video Settings -> Chunk Loading" switches between Standard, Smooth and Multi-Core chunk loading. When using "Chunk Loading: Multi-Core" make sure to Disable "Threaded Optimization" / "OpenGL Threading" in the graphics card control panel. For best results disable it globally, not only for java.exe or minecraft.exe.

Comment: I really have a difficult time turning graphics settings down with a system this capable. Do you have any idea of a mod for this? do you know of any existing? I could attemp to stick one up, but I have no idea how and I would have to almost completely rewrite the game's core, wouldn't I?

Comment: @spikespaz answer already updated with steps to enable it with OptiFine

Comment: I will try your most recent edit's suggestion when I am allowed the time, and will test the accuracy of your proposal. If it works, I will accept your answer. I can't seem to find the multicore rendering option in the settings however, as I have already attempted to find it. I know it exists, but just not where.

Comment: I cannot find the "Chunk Loading" option. Perhaps in an older version?

Comment: I am using Optifine on a A8 laptop and chunks load instantly with constant 60 FPS (I am not using shaders). So maybe multi core chunk loading is on by default since people say Minecraft only uses a single core which makes it slow on AMD processors which does not happen to me. I am also using Linux with OpenJDK Java 8